Centering a <p> element inside a header
I'm trying to center the <p> element inside the header but it's always off-center. I tried placing it in a grid and asked ChafGpt but it didn't work
I already tried putting it in a container and tried "margin: 0 auto" and it was supposed to be centered but it's not. I want it to be completely centered and ignore the logo but it doesn't seem to work


body {
  background-color: grey;
}

header {
  background-image: url('header.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 10vh;
}

#logo {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#page-description {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
<title>XboxPulse - News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="News.css">
<script src="News.js"></script>

<header>
  <img src="https://www.playourgames.nl/35770-medium_default/controller-wireless-xbox-pulse-red.jpg" alt="Xboxpulse" id="logo">
  <p id="page-description">News</p>
</header>




It looks pretty center to me now I made a snippet for you to have a [mcve]

sidenote, this does not seem to be an actual flow-text but a headline to me. As such you should not use a paragraph but an actual headline. Personally, I do not see any case where a paragraph would semantically fit into a header.

Looks center to me though, are you looking to center the icon as well on center aligned?

Add #page-description { width: fit-content; }

On the header, you can use flexbox to center the paragraph (horizontally and vertically) and flex-direction to place each sibling on a row. This way, the paragraph takes up 100% of the screen width despite it's sibling (image). Otherwise, you could use positioning or floating which will take elements out of the flow of the dom.


body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

header {
  background-image: url('header.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  align-self: start;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.6em;
}

#page-description {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.3em;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #707070;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
<header>
  <img src="https://www.playourgames.nl/35770-medium_default/controller-wireless-xbox-pulse-red.jpg" alt="Xboxpulse" id="logo">
  <p id="page-description">News</p>
</header>



